# addAll method in list java

Tags: java

I have been working around addAll method in java. But it wonders me as
What exactly is the difference between `public void addAll(List<T extends Person> persons)` and  `public void addAll(List<Person> persons)`

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about the declartaion, then the difference is that the `addAll(List<T extends Person> persons)` allows call with list which holds only subclasses of Person. While the `addAll(List<Person> persons)` will not accept such parameters. As `List<SubclassOfPerson>` cannot be assigned to `List<Parson>`

so:

```
class Child extends Person {};
List<Child> children = .....
```

calling `addAll(children)` makes sense, as any  child is a Person, but if the addAll was declared as `addAll(LIst<Person> persons)`, compiler would protest.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those methods calls would end up doing the same thing: add every element in the list argument to the list on which the method is invoked. The fact that compiler goes through a slightly different route to process your code has no implication on what ends up being executed nor on the final contents of the list.

Do you have a more specific question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand it, you'll have to go through this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

but in order to answer you, the difference is, that when you write

```
public void addAll(List<T extends Person> persons)
```

then you can call this method with `addAll(List<Worker> workers)` if you have `class Worker extends Person`. You cannot do that with second declaration though.